# How do I close a form automatically when finished?

Tags: c#, forms

I have `form1` calling `form2`, which is asking for contact information.  Once the form is filled in a save button is clicked.  At the end of the save event, I would like `form2` to close automatically returning to `form1`. Everything that I have found discusses closing form1, when form2 is opened.  Here is the code that I use to call `form2`.

```
customer_Ship_ID = textBox_Customer_Ship_ID.Text;
using (Form Customer_Add_Contact_Form = new Customer_Add_Contact_Form(customer_Ship_ID))
{
    Customer_Add_Contact_Form.ShowDialog();
}
```

The entire save event works perfectly and the user is finished.  If the form would just close without clicking the `'X'` in the upper right corner of the form, that would be great.

Comment: `Customer_Add.Contact_Form.Close()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.Close()` or `formName.Close()` after your Save event.

Comment: I actually tried  formName.Close()  and received the following error  'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'.  But  this.Close() worked perfectly.

Comment: @DaveHampel : If you want to use the latter option, use Customer_Add_Contact_Form.Close() instead of formName.Close() because your form name isn't 'formName'.

Comment: I did use my form name, Customer_Add_Contact_Form.Close(); and received the error message above which I couldn't find a clear answer for.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

use    this.Close()    at the end of your save event.